# i am tring to execute my maven project under automation testing using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

```
String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/login.html";  
driver.get(baseUrl);

// Get the WebElement corresponding to the Email Address(TextField) 
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));

// Get the WebElement corresponding to the Password Field       
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("passwd"));
```

Comment: Error pointing at WebElement line

Comment: And the error is? post full stack trace.

Comment: @saikiranthotakura check that elements with id `email` or name `passwd` are actually present/visible

Comment: @bhusak Yes there are elements with id email and name passwd

Comment: @Guy the error is pointing at WebElement line and at id

Comment: @saikiranthotakura I didn't ask *where* it is, I asked *what* it is.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");     
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();     
        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/login.html";     
        driver.get(baseUrl);     
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));        
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("passwd"));

Answer (score 0):

To send the credentials within the **Email address** and **Password** field you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/login.html");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#email"))).sendKeys("saikiran_thotakura");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#passwd")).sendKeys("saikiran_thotakura");
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: guru99]

Comment: The same error is what i got when i used .id also, help me out

Comment: @saikiranthotakura Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: after updating Error: The method cssSelector(String) is undefined for the type By

Comment: Upgrade to Selenium v3.141.59

Comment: Yes i upgraded too

Comment: Upgrade to ChromeDriver v76 and Chrome v76 as well